# Not able to set JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, java-home

I am editing conf/hadoop-env.sh to define JAVA_HOME variable. But i am getting these errors.

bin/hadoop: line 350: C:\Program: command not found
/bin/java: No such file or directoryes\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directoryk1.6.0_26\bin

I am using cygwin for hadoop 1.2.1 on my windows.

My java is installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin

I have set the environment variable and edited the env.sh file in this way.
export JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
When i am trying to echo JAVA_HOME,it is giving C:\Program only
But still it is not working for me. Can anyone please suggest me what to do. I have tried everything possible i read on internet.